# Vim in Windows Powershell no longer using colour and backspace no longer working

Tags: powershell, vim

I've been running Vim on my Windows system in the terminal (powershell) for a little while now, but at some point since the last time I ran it it has stopped using colours for syntax highlighting etc. I do not know what caused this, but I assume it must be Powershell as line numbers are still coloured yellow, and I even uninstalled and reinstalled Vim to try to get it working again.

I don't have any screenshots of what it looked like before, so you'll just have to trust me that things like strings were coloured differently, but here is a screenshot of how it is appearing now.

[image: screenshot of the colourless powershell]

additionally, backspace no longer works while in INSERT mode.

Comment: What is the filename? What does `:set ft?` return? Does `:syntax` print any syntax items?

Comment: :set ft returns 'filetype=' and :syntax prints 'No syntax items defined for this buffer'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I found a solution but I still do nut fully understand the cause of the issue if anyone wants to help! Basically, I went into my User directory and deleted the .vimrc file, and now its back working.

I think this is becasue I was doing some things that required I edit the .vimrc file. I ended up changing my mind and just wiped the file, but now instead of reading the default file, it was reading my BLANK .vimrc file.

I found this by looking up why backspace was no longer working in INSERT (you need to include a command in the .vimrc, which is included in the default, but was not included in my blank file obviously).

if anyone knows the line(s) that need to be included in the .vimrc to make syntax highlighting work again, that would be much appreciated! :D

Comment: See `:help defaults.vim` which explains what happened and how to get the defaults back.  `:help syntax` explains syntax highlighting. Or just put `:syntax enable` in your vimrc.